# How to TASKKILL a specific "program.exe" on a machine with many "program.exe" running

Tags: batch-file, command-line, taskkill

On my server i run a batch that call "program.exe", this program processes some data and close. If it doesn't close i will need to kill it.
The problem is that i could have many "program.exe" on the same machine but i have to kill only mine. Is it possible?

The batch file is called from an ASP page and it is launched with LocalSystem user privileges and does the following:

```
c:
cd \infos_a\exe
set infos=c:\infos_a\files\paolor
start /LOW program.exe #C:\inetpub\wwwroot\infospnt\bat\01\
```

if program.exe run more than 30sec it must be killed

Comment: What makes it *yours*? Is it the only one running under your logon credentials .. or ... ?

Comment: May be a solution in vbscript ==>  Killer-Selector.vbs

Comment: You can kill a single one using Taskkill it by process id (PID) instead of by name. How you identify which one, though...

Comment: execute `wmic process where "Caption='program.exe'" get /format:value` and see which attributes you can use to filter the one you want to kill.

Comment: maybe `tasklist /v` is helpful - depends on your exe...

Answer (score 0):

Taskkill help gives an example

```
taskkill /im program.exe /fi "Username eq MyName"
```